# PostgreSQL RSA-SHA256 password checking

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cryptography, dokuwiki, rsa-sha256

I have a node js app which stores passwords into a PostgreSQL database (Sequelize ORM) according to the function `setSaltAndPassword` detailed below

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

User.generateSalt = function() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64");
};


User.encryptPassword = function(plainText, salt) {
  return crypto
    .createHash("RSA-SHA256")
    .update(plainText)
    .update(salt)
    .digest("hex");
};

function setSaltAndPassword(user) {
  if (user.changed("password")) {
    user.salt = User.generateSalt();
    user.password = User.encryptPassword(user.password, user.salt());
  }
};
```

I want to be able to check a password for correctness with sql, so that I can integrate this db with a dokuwiki via the authpdo plugin [authpdo](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I've tried finding way to do this in PosgreSQL, and have found the [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) package, but it only has a single note on RSA at the bottom of the page stating:

"For RSA encryption you must create either DSA or RSA sign-only key as master and then add an RSA encryption subkey with gpg --edit-key."

Admittedly I have little experience with Cryptography and PostgreSQL, so I might be misunderstanding something here.

How should I go about verifying passwords via sql?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A digest algorithm of 'RSA-SHA256' doesn't really make sense, and indeed openssl simply treats this as equivalent to SHA256. Nothing to do with RSA at all, so you might as well specify it as SHA256.

Comment: RSA makes no sense for your use case. Here are [three](https://www.vaadata.com/blog/how-to-securely-store-passwords-in-database/) [online](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) [resources](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) that you should invest in understanding. In short, run the password through a cryptograpghic function and store the results. When you receive the password later, run it again through the same algorithm and compare the result with what you stored.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Specifying the method as SHA256 works in both node, and in constructing a hash when verifying from sql